# Code run in jupyter notebook acts differently than in pure python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

For years now, I have used jupyter notebooks for prototyping and testing code before placing it into modules for import. However, while working on this project, there have been multiple times where the same code acts differently in jupyter and in the imported pure python file. The most recent example of this is:

I am using a custom wrapper of scikit-learn's [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) to encode my pandas dataframe as the preprocessing step for my machine learning pipeline. Here is the function in my pure python file

```
def fit(data):
   encoder = Encoder()
   prepared = encoder.prep(data)
   encoded_data = encoder.fit_transform(prepared)
   encoder.fit_onehot(encoded_data)
```

When I import this code and run it I get the error

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'AL'

However, when I run this code in a jupyterlab notebook using the EXACT same dataframe

```
encoder = Encoder()
prepared = encoder.prep(data)
encoded_data = encoder.fit_transform(prepared)
encoder.fit_onehot(encoded_data)
```

everything works completely fine.

I cannot figure out what's really wrong because I can't replicate this behavior in my testing playground (jupyter).

Extra information:

- JupyterLab Beta Release Series Version 0.32.1
- Python 3.6.1

Comment: Confirm you're using not just the same python version but also pandas and other libraries. A new version of pandas was released on August 8. https://pandas.pydata.org

Comment: Do you have a small snippet of the data (just long enough to reproduce the problem)? I could try running it in 'pure python' to see what went wrong there. Exact versions of your packages would help, too (e.g. "pip list").

Comment: @LeoK I cannot even reproduce the problem if I am being honest. I just moved the same function (without changing it) to a different location in the file (just copy and pasted it at a different line number) and now it works.

Comment: Are you sure the `data` you send to both is exactly same?

Comment: @VivekKumar yes I am sure. To test this bug, I return the data given to the function from the function to the notebook and process using the same commands that would usually be in the function. The only explanation I can come up with is that the pandas dataframe changes when the data is returned.